# How do I convert some .Vb code to .CS code for asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a .CS file which uses SQL to retrieve some data and is called from a .VB file:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim urgentcare As New UrgentCareWaitTime()


    '' Urgent Care Display 
    ''   RGENT CARE 1 THEALL RD 
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall)

    ''new roc
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("542", Label171)
    ''ridge hills
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge)
    ''  210
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("194", Label210)

End Sub


Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim urgentcare As New UrgentCareWaitTime()


    '' Urgent Care Display 
    ''   RGENT CARE 1 THEALL RD 
    urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall)

    ''new roc
    urgentcare.Show("542", Label171)
    ''ridge hills
    urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge)
    ''  210
    urgentcare.Show("194", Label210)
End Sub
```

And in my ASP.NET file I have some textboxes:

```
<asp:Label ID="Labeltheall" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label171" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label210" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Labelridge" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
Last Updated: <asp:Label runat="Server"  id=lbl_time />
```

My asp page is `Default.aspx` and the helper file is `Default.aspx.cs`. How can I convert the VB code into CS so I can use it in my helper file to update those asp labels?

Comment: ASP.Net source code will be the same , change .vb file to .cs file by adding a c# webpage and copy the code into  
http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net source code will be the same , change .vb file to .cs file by adding a c# webpage and copy the code into [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();


    //' Urgent Care Display 
    //'   RGENT CARE 1 THEALL RD 
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);

    //'new roc
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
    //'ridge hills
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
    //'  210
    lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);

}


protected void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();


    //' Urgent Care Display 
    //'   RGENT CARE 1 THEALL RD 
    urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);

    //'new roc
    urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
    //'ridge hills
    urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
    //'  210
    urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);
}
```

Comment: I was finally able to get the online converter. Thanks you for the response UPVOTED and ACCEPTED because of being first to answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();


lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);

  }


 protected void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();
urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);
urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);
 }
```

to do it by yourself, please copy and paste your vb code here and click CONVERT TO C# http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: I was finally able to get the online converter. Thanks you for the response UPVOTED.

Answer (score 1):

Use Online [Vb to C# converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/).

else
Here is your C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();
urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);
urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was finally able to get the online converter. Thanks you for the response UPVOTED.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();


//' Urgent Care Display 
//'   RGENT CARE 1 THEALL RD 
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);

//'new roc
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
//'ridge hills
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
//'  210
lbl_time.Text = urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);

} 


protected void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();


//' Urgent Care Display 
//'   RGENT CARE 1 THEALL RD 
urgentcare.Show("195", Labeltheall);

//'new roc
urgentcare.Show("542", Label171);
//'ridge hills
urgentcare.Show("470", Labelridge);
//'  210
urgentcare.Show("194", Label210);
}
```